# How to get keyboard 'Enter' to trigger button press on Access form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to specify some code in a form in MS Access that means that when the 'Enter' button on the keyboard is pressed within a combobox, a form button is pressed (and it's corresponding code) is triggered.  I have tried the code below and when specifying KeyAscii = 13, yet both are still run if I tab through the combobox too.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
   Private Sub Plantspecies_KeyDown(KeyAscii As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then Command63_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Default` property of your button to "Yes" ("Other" tab), no code needed